# OS X 10.9.4 shows wrong used disk space

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, ssd, disk-space

The used disk space reported in About My Mac is inconsistent (MacBook Air, mid 2012).

[image: MacBook Air, mid 2012]

Notice that the used space for Apps is greater than my disk size. I tried different ways to fix it (Disk Utility, fsck command, etc.), but nothing helps.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I won't post this as an answer because I am simply posting a link. Try the solutions discussed here: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4467217

Answer (score 8, accepted):

These values come from the Spotlight index. So you could try rebuilding the Spotlight index to fix these values.

There are simple instructions from Apple here on [how to rebuild the Spotlight index](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht2409).

You can also do it from the command line using the [mdutil](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/mdutil.1.html) command. You'll be prompted for your password to run this command.

`sudo mdutil -E /`

Please note, whichever way you perform this task, it will take a while to run.

Answer (score -1):

See here: [500gb take up space on my HD, but don't belong to any visible file or folder](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/156159/500gb-take-up-space-on-my-hd-but-dont-belong-to-any-visible-file-or-folder/156167#156167)

In short:

- not all apps report files moved to trash, but trahs not emptied
- not all apps report backup files (esp. local snapshots of time machine)
- not all apps report ther caches and indexes