# 500gb take up space on my HD, but don't belong to any visible file or folder

Tags: hard-drive, macos, storage

I've got a problem: 500gb take up space on my HD, but don't belong to any visible file or folder. This may have something to do with a disk image of 500gb I created and deleted some time ago. Is there anything that can be done with this except backing up the disk, reformatting and copying the contents back in? (That will take a lot of time.) The format of the disk is Mac OS extended, encrypted, journaled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Did you emptied the trash after removing the image file (if it was removed in Finder).
2. Check in About this MAC > Storage, if this 500 GB is not used by Backups. If it is, that means that it might be local snapshot of time Machine backup including this file. See http://support.apple.com/en-us/ht4878

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you scan your Disk with '[Daisydisk](http://www.daisydiskapp.com/)' and locate the files that are eating up your Diskspace.

Answer (score 1):

Occasionally a disk image will unmount but not release the space. If you are Terminal-fluent, kill `diskimages-helper`. Or reboot (cold, full-power-down reboot. Good time for software update too.)